# How to remove dead handles

Tags: r, curl

I am developing an API client in R. I need to test the HTTP calls from time to time. But each time I build and install, and make a request afterwards, I get the following error:

```
 Error in curl::handle_setopt(opts$url$handle, .list = opts$options) : 
  handle is dead
```

I am not using [curl](https://github.com/jeroen/curl) directly, the requests are made through [crul](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crul/). So I did not create the dead handle, otherwise I would try to reset it using `curl::handle_reset()` or something similar.

My current fix is to restart my R session, which works well but is highly annoying. Is there a better way to make the dead handle go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very specific to [crul](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crul/) but then so is the question (unfortunately the title does not suggests so after Flimzy's edits).

The easiest way to remove the dead handle is to remove the original client object. For example:

1. Create a new client by calling `client = crul::HttpClient$new(url = url)`
2. Run build and install.
3. Call it again to drop the old client object and create a new one: `client = crul::HttpClient$new(url = url)`

Done. No session restart needed.